# How do I manage Ruby installations on production machines with sparse resources?

Tags: linux, debian, ruby

I have a virtual Debian host with about 256MB RAM running a little Rails application that won't need more. As Ruby 2.0 is coming along, it should be upgraded in the near future. The last time I upgraded Ruby, I had to stop the app and expand the swap partition to build it successfully, which took almost a day to complete.

Has anyone here have a tip or a good way how to put new Rubies on production machines without troubling a Rails application running on it?

I thought of setting up a virtual machine locally and then copying over the built Ruby, or nice the build process, but this would then maybe result in an ETA of ~2 days on such a little machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you can build on another machine and  copy over the binaries.
Or, you can use Ruby provided by Debian, so you don't have to rebuild when updating.